# PDO Error 42000 on Insert Statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hi I have the following with the below code? I have another statement which works but it is to another table and without the project_id column.

```
(
    [0] => 42000
    [1] => 1064
    [2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'change (title, description, project_id) VALUES ('Test1', 'Test1', '1')' at line 1
)
```

---

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO change (title, description, project_id) VALUES (:title, :description, :project_id)";
$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array(":title" => $title,
        ":description" => $description,
        ":project_id" => $row_id));

$arr = $query->errorInfo();
print_r($arr);
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Specifically, `change` is a reserved word, you need to quote it with backticks.

Comment: try to encapsulate table name with `\`change\``

Comment: Barmer, how can i reward you with the correct answer? You're also helping me with another question which relates to this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make tables always check here for reserved keywords in [**mysql**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html)

Your table name is a reserved keyword which is why you have these errors.

Use backticks to fix the problem. But i will recommend that you change the table name.

Sometimes prople find it hard to locate the backticks, it's above your tab key if you are using a normal qwerty or azerty keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

Always encapsulate your table and field names in backticks:

```
INSERT INTO `change` (`title`, `description`, `project_id`) VALUES (:title, :description, :project_id)
```

In this case: `CHANGE` is a keyword in MySQL, so your statement doesn't interpret it as a table name.